# Magento2.2x How to change backend product grid price column base on store view

Tags: magento2

Is there any way the price column of the backend product list grid can display local price and currency according to store view?

[image: display]

Comment: how do you expect this to work for multiple storeviews?

Comment: In Magento you cannot change price at store view level suppose if you will change price for English store it will be change for all other store as well.

Comment: For example, the default price is US dollar. When I log into the store view of Australia's backend, I want the product list to display the Australian dollar.
On the other hand, even I log in to the website level(EU), the product list still displays the default price(US).